# open a long <select> dropdown to specific option when the dropdown is first clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, focus

I have a large dropdown list containing possible answer like this:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect" required="" >
        <option value="-100"  > -100% </option>
        <option value="-99"  > -99% </option>
        <option value="-98"  > -98% </option>
        <option value="0"  > 0% </option>
        <option value="101" selected = "" hidden = ""> ----- </option>
```

going from -100 to 100.
When the dropdown is first clicked, I would like it to open (and select) at a prespecified value, i.e. at 0.

I have tried this:

```
$('#mySelect').one('focus', function() {
    $(this).children('option[value=0]').prop('selected',true);
});
```

and this works well in Chrome, but it doesn't work in Firefox, which is a problem for me. (edit) As mentioned in the comments, in Firefox above script selects the correct option, but dropdown is not scrolled to that value.

Help with a working solution in both Firefox and Chrome would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a fiddle of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/monni/an4guvse/28/

Comment: why have the `-----` option as the default selected value instead of just 0?

Comment: When the box is not clicked, it should not show any values.

Comment: Just make `0` the default value. Modern browsers will automatically scroll to this option in the list to show it, you don't need to write any code to do that. Even if you tried, it wouldn't work, as you cannot programmatically interact with the options list itself.

Comment: Also, why use a `select` for this at all? A `range` input seems to make far more sense: https://jsfiddle.net/ux1p0d2v/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for the comment. But I don't want to show any "real" value before the dropdown is clicked. Would this be possible?

Comment: Works for me in Firefox as far as setting the value. The only difference is the scrolling to that option in the various browsers

Comment: @charlietfl, yes that is exactly the problem. I would like it to scroll to that specific option at the first click

Comment: OK then you should [edit] the question because you only stated "it doesn't work" but weren't specific. Part of the operation does indeed work

Comment: @charlietfl. Okey, the quesiton is now edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want to show any "real" value before the dropdown is clicked

Given this statement, in the comments, what you're attempting to do is not workable. The actions available on an options list within a `select` are vey limited, and this behaviour is non-standard.

I'd argue it's even counter intuitive and will confuse your users and cause more problems than it solves.

What you're attempting to achieve seems like it could be better solved by using a `range` input:

```js
$('#foo').on('input', e => $(e.target).next().text(e.target.value + '%'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" min="-100" max="100" value="0" id="foo" />
<span></span>
```

Comment: Yes, I understand it isn't really practical but this is actually part of web based experiment that my professor is doing, and he would like to use this dropdown menu to show all the possible answers.

Comment: Then unfortunately what you're attempting to do is not possible in a reliable, cross-browser way.